# export formatted text to pdf

Tags: delphi, pdf

I have a `TRichEditView` with formatted text inside of it, like this:

```
**Header**

**paragraph 1 title**
__________________
paragraph 1 line 1
paragraph 1 line 2
paragraph 1 line 3

**paragraph 2 title**
__________________
paragraph 2 line 1
paragraph 2 line 2
paragraph 2 line 3
```

I want to export the text to a PDF file.

Right now, the project is using PDFLibrary with drawing each page on the PDF file, but if the number of lines is about 9000 then this takes a long time to export, like 15 minutes.

I'm working on creating the PDF file line-by-line, but I wonder if there is a faster way to convert formatted text to PDF?

This is a part of code that I'm trying to export:

```
var
  pdfLibrary: TDebenuPDFLibrary;
begin
  ...
  pdfLibrary.SetInformation(5, '---'); // Creator
  pdfLibrary.SetMeasurementUnits(2);           // Inches
  pdfLibrary.SetOrigin(1);                     // Top left
  pdfLibrary.CompressImages(1);                // Flate compression
  pdfLibrary.CompressFonts(1);                 // Compress all subsequently added fonts
  pdfLibrary.SetPageSize('A4');

  // Set current page size. This will be inherited for new pages
  pdfLibrary.SetPageDimensions(pageSetup.Size.Width, pageSetup.Size.Height);

  marginRect.Create(0, 0,
    trunc(pageSetup.Size.Width * TResolutionHelper.STANDARD_WINDOWS_DPI),
    trunc(pageSetup.Size.Height * TResolutionHelper.STANDARD_WINDOWS_DPI));

  cntr := 0;
  fontID := pdfLibrary.AddStandardFont(5);
  while cntr < 1 do //for now just do for first line
  begin
    if cntr > 1 then
      if pdfLibrary.NewPage = 0 then
        raise Exception.Create(format('%d page cannot be added', [cntr]));

      //pdfLibrary.SelectFont( fontID );
      pdfLibrary.SetTextSize( RVStyle1.TextStyles[1].SizeDouble );
      pdfLibrary.SelectPage(0);

      x := (pdfLibrary.PageWidth / 2) - pdfLibrary.GetTextWidth( tseHeader.GetItemText(0) );
      pdfLibrary.DrawText( x, 0.5, tseHeader.GetItemText(0) );

      inc(cntr);
    end;
  ...
end;
```

Right now, the `SetTextAlign()` is not aligning, and this takes a long while to finish. I'm looking for something that make more sense.

Comment: my actual code is in a big project if I want to show something here that make seance I have to show almost half of the project

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the same issue. Without any code, nobody can tell you if you are doing something wrong with it.

Comment: I'm looking for another solution not code correction, I wonder if anyone tried to do the same thing

Comment: If we can't see what you are doing, we can't tell you if it can be done another way. In any case, asking for recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow anyway.

Comment: I did add a sample, now do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I would try a third-party reporting library that supports exporting to PDF.. ReportBuilder is a good one..

Comment: You say `SetTextAlign()` is the problem, but there is no `SetTextAlign()` in the code you showed.  Did you mean `SetTextSize()`?

Comment: Which version of Delphi?  Anything even remotely new will have either Rave or FastReport.

Comment: I've change the setTextALign with my own version of finding the center of the screen, because it was not setting the text in the middle of the page,  Remy Lebeau

Comment: I kind of solved finding the center of the page! (pdfLibrary.PageWidth / 2) this is enoght there is no need of finding the center of the text and the rest it is drawing the text in the center of the line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of solving my issue

```
procedure TfrmDemo.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  QP: TDebenuPDFLibrary;
  X: Integer;
  footer: string;
  footerHeight: double;
  textHeight: double;
begin
  dlgSave.FileName := 'Rotated.pdf';
  if dlgSave.Execute then
  begin
    QP := TDebenuPDFLibrary.Create;
    try
      if QP.UnlockKey(edtLicenseKey.Text) = 1 then
      begin
        footer := 'footer is here!';
        QP.AddStandardFont(8);
        footerHeight := QP.GetTextHeight;

        // Set the paper size
        QP.SetPageSize('A4');

        // Set the origin to the top-left corner
        QP.SetOrigin(1);

        // Set the measurement units to millimetres
        QP.SetMeasurementUnits(1);

        // Add a standard font
        QP.AddStandardFont(11);  // Times Roman Bold Italic

        QP.SetTextSize(10);

        QP.SetTextAlign( 1 );

        I := 0;
        textHeight := QP.GetTextHeight;
        while 10 + (textHeight * I) < qp.PageHeight - footerHeight - textHeight do
        begin
          QP.DrawText( (qp.PageWidth / 2)  , 10 + (textHeight * I),
          '1 Quick PDF Library, Quick PDF Library, Quick PDF Library, Quick PDF Library, Quick PDF Library');
          inc(I);
        end;

        qp.DrawLine( 10, 10 + (textHeight * I), qp.PageWidth - 10, 10 + (textHeight * I) );
        inc(I);

        QP.AddStandardFont(8);
        QP.SetTextSize(8);
        QP.DrawText( (qp.PageWidth / 2)  , 10 + (textHeight * I), footer);

        // Compress the contents of the file
        QP.CompressContent;

        // Save the file
        QP.SaveToFile(dlgSave.FileName);
      end else
        MessageDlg('The license key is invalid or has expired.', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    finally
      QP.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```